# Chemical simulation software for a person who is not in the chemistry field but has a basic knowledge about chemistry

Tags: windows, simulation, scientific-computing

In my research I need to see, if I mix chemical A with chemical B, then what is the outcome? if it's another chemical, then I need to see the resultant chemical's 1. Density 2. Melting point 3.reaction time 4. if it will have any risks while performing the mixing in real life (explosions, fire etc etc)

What I'm actually trying to do is: I have a specific chemical, I want to know which chemicals or solutions will produce a rock-hard precipitate or crystals by reacting with my specific chemical.

The software should be accurate too, because I will use this for my PhD. I'm not in the chemistry field but my PhD involves inorganic chemistry.

I have only basic knowledge about chemistry, please don't ask me to go and read a book of chemistry or complete a chemistry degree as there's no time for that, finding the right chemical is a fraction of my research and I'm exhausted with the PhD already :)